# Getting this error InvalidArgumentError: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU [[node sequential_5/max_pooling2d_5/MaxPool

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I get this error when I run the code below after I have build the CNN

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=27)


InvalidArgumentError:  Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[node sequential_5/max_pooling2d_5/MaxPool (defined at <ipython-input-142-acc519fcce62>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_2871]
```

My input_shape currently has

```
(1, 100, 100)
```

And my CNN is the following

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,3,padding='same', input_shape= input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same' ))

model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(numclasses))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I have used K.image_data_format() to define the channels for the dimension

```
numchannels = 1

if numchannels == 1:
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        Img_data = np.expand_dims(Img_data, axis=1)
        print(Img_data.shape)
    else:
        Img_data = np.expand_dims(Img_data, axis = 4)
        print (Img_data.shape)

else: 
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        Img_data=np.rollaxis(Img_data,3,1)
        print (Img_data.shape)
```